# Android ADB copy from /data/data/com.xxx to /sdcard

Tags: android, linux, adb

I'm trying to copy from /data/data/com.stuff to sdcard so I can ADB pull it to my pc.

So far, I have tried:

> mv '/data/data/com.android.providers.settings' '/sdcard'

-Gave `failed on ... - Cross-device link`

> cp '/data/data/com.android.providers.settings' '/sdcard'

Gave - `cp: ... is a directory (not copied)`

> cat '/data/data/com.android.providers.settings' '/sdcard'

Gave - `cat: ... Is a directory
-cat: /sdcard: Is a directory`

so... I'm stuck and have no idea how to copy it to sdcard...
Any ideas?

Comment: Do u try it on the real device? If it so do u have a root?

Comment: yes, it is rooted

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you are trying to copy your folder /data/data/com.android.providers.settings to sdcard folder 
so, you can do it by pull this folder into your local machine

```
adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.setting C:/folder_name
```

and then push your folder into device SD card

```
adb push C:/folder_name /sdcard/folder_name
```

Comment: it says
pull: building file list...
0 files pulled. 0 files skipped
It's not pulling any file...

Comment: are you are sure, that folder, who are you are trying to copy, non-empty?